# If null else not working

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to execute a msg if the `location` is null, and another msg if it is not null, so I'm trying use the [elvis-operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) as `a?.let{} ?: run{}` statement, but the `run` part is not reachable, and it tells me it is not required nor non-nullable!

The function I'm getting the error with, is:

```
getLocation(
           context,
                { location ->
                    location?.let {
                        msg = ("As of: ${Date(it.time)}, " +
                                "I am at: http://maps.google.com/?q=@" +
                                "${it.latitude}, ${it.longitude}, " +
                                "my speed is: ${it.speed}")
                    } ?: run { . // Getting error here
                        msg = "Sorry, it looks GPS is off, no location found\""
                    }

                    sendSMS(
                            context,
                            address,
                            msg,
                            subId
                    )
                }
        )
```

Th `getLocation` function is:

```
object UtilLocation {
    private lateinit var l : Location

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun getLocation(context: Context, callback: (Location) -> Unit) {
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context!!)

        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
                    this.l = location!!
                    callback.invoke(this.l)
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: location argument in your lambda is not nullable, you don't need that `?.let{}`. If the location is null your code crashes in `addOnSuccessListener{}`

Comment: Thinking a bit about it, you could change it to `msg = location?.let { ... } ?: { ... }` instead of using `run` afterwards

Comment: Do you have any questions to my answer? Please consider accepting my answer or tell me what information do you need...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `fun getLocation(context: Context, callback: (Location) -> Unit)`, the parameter `Location` of `callback` is NotNull, so it's never null, this is why `location?.let` causes a warning -- it's never null so it's impossible to enter the `?: run` part of the expression.

AFAIK you want this code (parameter of `callback` is made Nullable, removed unnecessary NotNull assertion, add null check instead of assertion):

```
object UtilLocation {
    private lateinit var l : Location

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun getLocation(context: Context, callback: (Location?) -> Unit) {
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
                    if (location != null) this.l = location
                    callback.invoke(this.l)
                }
    }
}
```

And now this code work. I've did a little refactor to make it look nicer

```
getLocation(context) { location ->
    msg = location?.let {
        "As of: ${Date(it.time)}, " +
                "I am at: http://maps.google.com/?q=@" +
                "${it.latitude}, ${it.longitude}, " +
                "my speed is: ${it.speed}"
    } ?: run {
        "Sorry, it looks GPS is off, no location found\""
    }

    sendSMS(context, address, msg, subId)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the nicer way of rewriting my code.